# Power BI comparing different columns with different rows

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

Hello I have the following table:

```
Date/time 1                   Date/time 2
1/1/2021  12:00:01 PM         1/1/2021  12:00:10 PM
1/1/2021  12:00:08 PM         1/1/2021  12:00:50 PM
1/1/2021  12:00:35 PM         1/1/2021  12:01:40 PM
1/1/2021  12:02:03 PM         1/1/2021  12:02:08 PM
```

I need a new column that will return the following data

```
column 3                   
1/1/2021  12:00:01 PM       
1/1/2021  12:00:01 PM      
1/1/2021  12:00:01 PM      
1/1/2021  12:02:03 PM
```

In other words, it should be the min of the date/time 1 as long as the date/time 1 < than the date/time 2 in the previous row. Once the Date/time 1 is bigger than the previous date/time 2, then it should repeat the same sequence and take the min date/time 1 until it's bigger than the previous date/time 2.

How can I proceed with this? I am open to solutions using power query or dax

Answer (score 1):

With `DAX`

If you have a table like this called `_tbl`

```
| Index | Date/time 1          | Date/time 2          |
|-------|----------------------|----------------------|
| 1     | 1/1/2021 12:00:01 PM | 1/1/2021 12:00:10 PM |
| 2     | 1/1/2021 12:00:08 PM | 1/1/2021 12:00:50 PM |
| 3     | 1/1/2021 12:00:35 PM | 1/1/2021 12:01:40 PM |
| 4     | 1/1/2021 12:02:03 PM | 1/1/2021 12:02:08 PM |
| 5     | 1/1/2021 12:02:06 PM | 1/1/2021 12:02:10 PM |
| 6     | 1/1/2021 12:02:04 PM | 1/1/2021 12:02:12 PM |
```

You can write the following two measures to reach your goal

```
_lastNonBlank =
VAR _index =
    MAX ( _tbl[Index] )
VAR _preceding = _index - 1
VAR _dt1 =
    MAX ( _tbl[Date/time 1] )
VAR _dt2 =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( _tbl[Date/time 2] ),
        FILTER ( ALLSELECTED ( _tbl ), _tbl[Index] = _preceding )
    )
VAR _lastNonBlank =
    IF ( _dt1 > _dt2, _index )
RETURN
    _lastNonBlank


_dt1 =
VAR _index =
    MAX ( _tbl[Index] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( _tbl[Date/time 1] ),
        FILTER (
            ALLSELECTED ( _tbl ),
            _tbl[Index] <= _index
                && [_lastNonBlank] <> BLANK ()
        )
    )
```

[image: S1]

Answer (score 0):

These kind of operations are not very trivial in power query context. This is not to say that it can't be done, but I think the easiest way to go about this would be with a bit of help from Python.

Power BI suppoert running python scripts on a table, where you pull the table into a pandas data frame. You can then manipulate it in Python, and store the desired result in another dataframe. You can then unpack this back to a power query table! Below a snippet of what your python code could look like!

[image: python snip]

Now this is by no means the most elegant way to do this in python, but it is syntactically short and works and is quite easy to understand.

You can add the python script from the power query editor by going to the transform tab and selecting the python icon

any dataframe in your python code can be extracted to a table in power Bi

Comment: Thanks! Sadly I cant use Python but I appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

You can use the row-level to get the minimum date time. At the moment of creating a column, you can access the row-level, and use `List.Min` to get the minimum value.
Ignore the `Source` step, that only to reproduce your data.
The solution is on the step `NewColumn`.

## Power Query Code

```
let
  Source = Table.FromRows(
    Json.Document(
      Binary.Decompress(
        Binary.FromText(
          "i45WMjDUByIjAyNDBUMjKwMDKwNDJR1MUUMDpVgdbKotsKk2xaHa2BRTtaGVCVbVQGSMqdoIZGNsLAA=", 
          BinaryEncoding.Base64
        ), 
        Compression.Deflate
      )
    ), 
    let
      _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true])
    in
      type table [#"Date/time 1" = _t, #"Date/time 2" = _t]
  ), 
  NewColumn = Table.AddColumn(
    Source, 
    "Min DateTime", 
    (row) => List.Min({row[#"Date/time 1"], row[#"Date/time 2"]})
  )
in
  NewColumn
```

## Output

| Date/time 1 | Date/time 2 | Min DateTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2021 12:00:01 | 01/01/2021 12:00:10 | 01/01/2021 12:00:01 |
| 01/01/2021 12:00:08 | 01/01/2021 12:00:50 | 01/01/2021 12:00:08 |
| 01/01/2021 12:00:35 | 01/01/2021 12:01:40 | 01/01/2021 12:00:35 |
| 01/01/2021 12:02:03 | 01/01/2021 12:02:08 | 01/01/2021 12:02:03 |

## Original Table

| Date/time 1 | Date/time 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 01/01/2021 12:00:01 | 01/01/2021 12:00:10 |
| 01/01/2021 12:00:08 | 01/01/2021 12:00:50 |
| 01/01/2021 12:00:35 | 01/01/2021 12:01:40 |
| 01/01/2021 12:02:03 | 01/01/2021 12:02:08 |

Comment: Thanks.. but your solution returns the minimum of the two columns.. that's not what I am looking for..

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do what you want:
By adding a column which is offset by one from `Date/Time 2`, we make the comparison simpler (and this method is faster than using an Index column)

*note that your question is ambiguous as to what should happen if the datetime in column 1 is equal to the datetime in the preceding row of column 2. You may need to change the equality test depending on what you want to do.*

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table7"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date/Time 1", type datetime}, {"Date/Time 2", type datetime}}),

//add an offset column relative to column2
    prevRow = Table.FromColumns(
        Table.ToColumns(#"Changed Type") & {{null} & List.RemoveLastN(#"Changed Type"[#"Date/Time 2"])}, 
        type table [#"Date/Time 1" = datetime, #"Date/Time 2" = datetime, prevRow=datetime]),

//add custom column with "the test"
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(prevRow, "Custom", each 
        if [prevRow] = null then [#"Date/Time 1"] else 
            if [#"Date/Time 1"] < [prevRow] then null else [#"Date/Time 1"], type datetime),

//remove unneeded column and fill down the custom column
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"prevRow"}),
    #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Removed Columns",{"Custom"})
in
    #"Filled Down"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An aproach using just 1 line of code would be te following. It's a bit less efficient in terms of speed and memory, but if your dataset is not too large it should work fine.

1: Duplicate your table by right clicking it in the Query's section of the power query editor. In the duplicated table, use group by, remove the suggested aggregation, and select min and Date/Time 1 as your column. This table now only contains the minimum of Date/Time 1. Add a column with the value 1 to the minimum table ( will make sense a bit later)

2: In you Original table, add an index column from the add column tab. Then add also a column which is this index +1. Now using merge queries, perform a self join (merging the table with itself ) of type left, where you match the index of your table on the index +1. ( Another way to do this would be to duplicate the table again and then merge )

3: after merging, expand the added query and select only the column of Date/Time 2 ( Use left outer join) and rename it to prevtime2 (or whatever you like)

4: Add a column with the value 1 and use merge query to join the table on the table containing the minimum from step one, use the columns containing one from both tables (this is basically a fully unconditional full outer join ). Expand the column containig the minimum and rename it to somthing like MinDateTime.

5: Add a custom column like this

[image]

And you are all set ( although you may need to handle the very first row manually still, the rest should be good! )

May seem like a lot of steps but you can actually do it quite quickly. You can just remove all other columns you dont need once you optain the result of step 5. You do end up with 1/2 extra tables in your model (depending on wether you used the self join or not ) but you can just hide them or give them good names so that they won't be used.